# INOUT parameter failure for stored procedure called from prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

Here's my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testProc`(INOUT num INT(11), INOUT num2 INT(11))
BEGIN
    set num2 = num+7;
END
```

Here's the code that calls it:

```
$newId = 1;
$type - 2;

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'call testProc(?,?)')) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $type,$newId);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $type,$newId);
    echo $newId;
    exit;
    }
```

I expected $newId to hold 9. It still holds 1.

`mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` seems redundant, as I don't actually have a result set (and I think its existence causes bugs later because I don't have a result set), but this code falls over without it (My actual code doesn't but I don't know why). That's may be moot though.

Please can anyone show me how to change this code to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php) states that you've got to use session variables (MySQL sessions, not PHP)

> INOUT/OUT parameter
>
> The values of INOUT/OUT parameters are accessed using session variables.

`mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` is to be used to bind values from a resultset like a `SELECT` statement. This could be a `SELECT` statement in a stored procedure, see the chapter [Stored Routine Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-routines-syntax.html) of the MySQL manual:

> MySQL supports a very useful extension that enables the use of regular
>   SELECT statements (that is, without using cursors or local variables)
>   inside a stored procedure. The result set of such a query is simply
>   sent directly to the client.

So you could do it with

```
// set your IN parameter using a prepared statement
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SET @type := ?')) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $type);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}

// do the same for your second parameter 
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SET @newId := ?')) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $newId);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}

// No need to use a prepared statement for the procedure call anymore
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'call testProc(@type, @newId)');
// If the procedure would return something else than the INOUT or OUT parameter
// then you would get this result now

// getting the value of the INOUT parameter
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT @newId as newId');
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);             
var_dump($row);
```

Output:

```
Connected to databasearray(1) {
  ["newId"]=>
  string(1) "9"
}
```

**Note:**
Error handling left as an exercise to show only the main issue.